# The font "IBMPlexSerif-Light" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, packages, sans-serif

I try to use “IBM Plex Sans Light” font then I just try to follow what describe [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ibmplexsanslight/). So my MWE is the given LaTeX [source](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ibmplexsanslight/ibmplexsanslight.tex) founded in that page. I just put in my MWE’s directory the [plex-otf packages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/plex-otf/latex/plex-otf.sty).

Then, I compile with `xelatex` but I get the following error:

```
Using file names for the Plex font
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[IBMPlexSerif-Light.otf]/OT', contains '['

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "IBMPlexSerif-Light" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.151   ]
```

So, where can I find the “IBMPlexSerif-Light” font? the `plex-otf` package in the documentation was not suposed to contain it descriptions?

Answer (score 3):

The [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/plex-otf/README.md) of the package reads:

> Package plex-otf supports the free otf-fonts from the IBM Plex project which is available from GitHub or already part of your system (Windows/Linux/...)

So you must have the font preinstalled on your system (which doesn't make sense at all for a package that only works with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; you can just use `fontspec`). Anyway, either download the fonts from [Github](https://github.com/IBM/plex/releases/latest) and install it or use the [`plex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/plex) packages, which comes with the fonts.

If you choose the second option, be aware that the actual package import isn't `\usepackage{plex}`, but one of these:

- `\usepackage{plex-serif}`
- `\usepackage{plex-mono}`
- `\usepackage{plex-sans}`

Read the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/plex/README) for examples.

---

### MWE

Here a minimum, complete and verifiable example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}    % To turn headers sans-serif
\usepackage{plex-serif} % Load Plex-Serif
\usepackage{plex-sans}  % Load Plex-Sans
\usepackage{plex-mono}  % Load Plex-Mono
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Dummy text

\begin{document}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\section{Introduction}
\kant[1] % dummy text

\section{What is this}
This is an MWE showing \texttt{plex-sans}, \texttt{plex-mono} and \texttt{plex-serif} in action. 

Here a naïve factorial implemented in Julia:
\begin{verbatim}
    function factorial(n::T)::T where T <: Integer
        if n ≤ 1
            return 1;
        else
            return n * factorial(n-1);
        end
    end
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The result is (look at the ≤ symbol):
[image: Document using Plex fonts]

Although it's far different from the default Computer Modern font, here a comparative.
[image: Document using CMU fonts]

This example is available on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/kdnvwqnpbvdx

Comment: For the second solutuion, the `plex-{serf,mono,sans}` packages doesn’t change nothing, I still get the same error message.. For the first solution, I installed the font, and again, I still get the same error message. This solutions aren’t usefull.

Comment: I added an MWE for the second solution. In addition to _load_ the fonts, you need to _use_ them as well (except `serif`, which is used by default in LaTeX).

Comment: I still get the same error message as in the first message. ”The font "IBMPlexSans-Regular" cannot be found.”.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this issue is to download the fonts directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/IBM/plex) and copy them to your working directory. I like to create a folder named 'fonts', which helps reduce the clutter.

Once that's done, one can simple use the `fontspec` package (works only with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex) to define your font. You can find the package documentation (a very good one!) and files [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en).

If you still have issues, this [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX) page might be helpful!

P.S. Only a beginner TeX user and this is my first community post. Hope this answer helps anyone with same issue in the future.

Comment: the fonts are already on CTAN!

Comment: Downloading the fonts from GitHub and using `fontspec` is already part of Héliton Martins' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the package `plex` which installs all Plex-Fonts. The package `plex-otf` handles only the use of the opentype definitions for `fontspec`. It does *not* install the fonts!!

this works with `xelatex` and `lualatex` *and* installed package `plex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usefilenames,RMstyle=Light,SSstyle=Light,
     TTstyle=Light,DefaultFeatures={Ligatures=Common}]{plex-otf}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]